# Regex Pattern for checking the first letter of each word in a string if its Uppercase in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

for example my string is **Foo Bar.**
this string should match the pattern.

if the string is **Foo bar.**
the string should not match.

if the string is **Foo Bar Foobar** 
the string should match

if the string is **Foo.** it should also match.

so far I only have this pattern

```
 (^[A-Z]{1}.*(\s)?$)+
```

Basically I will only accept a string where each First letter of each word is Uppercase

Comment: Might be simpler to do a pattern to match any word starting with something other than an uppercase letter (and negate the result).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use this regex:

```
^(\b[A-Z]\w*\s*)+$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM5qK7/2)

Comment: how to add length to it? i mean if I want to allow total length of characters upto 50?

Answer (score 9):

I'd see if your string does NOT match something like this:

```
/\b[a-z]/
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to use this:

```
#(\s|^)([a-z0-9-_]+)#i
```

Comment: `#i`? Question is tagged "javascript".

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

`/(^[a-z]| [a-z])/ig`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this?

```
/^([A-Z]\w*\s*)+$/
```

[Live Demo](https://regexr.com/6vu2u)