# Javascript RegEx to XML Schema RegEx

Tags: javascript, xml, xsd

I have this Javascript pattern

```
^(\b[A-Z]\w*(\s|\.)*)+$
```

I tried using it on my XML Schema

```
<xs:pattern value="^(\b[A-Z][a-z]*(\s|\.)*)+$">
```

But when I validate I received an error saying **InvalidRegex: Pattern value '^(\b[A-Z][a-z]*(\s|.)*)+$' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'This expression is not supported in the current option setting.'.**

Is there a way for my Javascript pattern to work on my XML Schema pattern?

Comment: According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html it doesn't support the ^ and $ anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not always possible to transform JS regex to XSD regex, some things like word-boundary, lookaheads and others are not supported in XSD regex, as mentioned in [Michael Kay answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37133553/3870761).

Based on [your other question asking for a regex to test that all words starts with an uppercase character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130556/regex-pattern-for-checking-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-if-its-uppe), you can write another regex valid for XSD, such as this one, that tests that after one (or multiple) spaces or dots the following character should not be a lowercase letter.

```
([^\s\.]*([\s\.]+[^a-z])?)*[\s\.]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, XSD regular expressions are implicitly anchored to the ends of the string, so you can (and must) omit the "^" and "$".

The more difficult problem is the \b. Outside square brackets, \b in Javascript matches a "word boundary", that is a boundary between a sequence of ASCII letters and digits, and a sequence consisting of non-(ASCII letters and digits).

Looking more carefully, I can't see what the \b actually contributes to your regex, other than ensuring there is at least one character present in the string. As far as I can see, your regex can be simplified to

```
[A-Za-z\s\.]+
```