# Exclude expressin '?!' cannot be validated

Tags: regex, xml, eclipse, xsd

In my xsd schema, there is one particular regex `<xs:pattern value="(?!TR)[A-Z]{2}"/>` pattern which causes an error. I want just ignore 'TR' and match all other country codes. Although the regular expression works fine in several online editors, Eclipse says:

> InvalidRegex: Pattern value '(?!TR)[A-Z]{2}' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: 'This expression is not supported in the current option setting.'

Despite it's a simple expression, cannot figure that out why it cannot be validated. With this error, I cannot deploy xsd file to the service bus. Is there a problem about aclipse itself or sth else?

all advises are much appreciated!

[image: it works as desired]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript RegEx to XML Schema RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131767/javascript-regex-to-xml-schema-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XML Schema regex flavor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) does not support lookarounds. The non-lookaround version of your regex is

```
[A-SU-Z][A-Z]|[A-Z][A-QS-Z]
```

Or, using the [character class subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html):

```
[A-Z-[T]][A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z-[R]]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mETUUr/1)

Just note I used `^` and `$` in the demo only because the flavor is PCRE there. In XSD `pattern`, the regex is anchored by default, no `^` and `$` are necessary.

**Pattern details**:

- `[A-SU-Z]` (or [A-Z-[T]])`- any uppercase ASCII letter other than`T`
- `[A-Z]` - any uppercase ASCII letter
- `|`  - or
- `[A-Z]`  - any uppercase ASCII letter
- `[A-QS-Z]` (or `[A-Z-[R]]`) - any uppercase ASCII letter other than `R`