# Extract first letter in each word in R

Tags: r, regex

I had a data.frame with some categorical variables. Let's suppose `sentences` is one of these variables:

```
sentences <- c("Direito à participação e ao controle social",
               "Direito a ser ouvido pelo governo e representantes", 
               "Direito aos serviços públicos",
               "Direito de acesso à informação")
```

For each value, I would like to extract just the first letter of each word, ignoring if the word has 4 letters or less (e, de, à, a, aos, ser, pelo), My goal is create acronym variables. I expect the following result:

```
[1] "DPCS", "DOGR", "DSP", "DAI
```

I tried to make a pattern subset using `stringr` with a regex pattern founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130556/regex-pattern-for-checking-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-if-its-uppe):

```
library(stringr)
pattern <- "^(\b[A-Z]\w*\s*)+$"
str_subset(str_to_upper(sentences), pattern)
```

But I got an error when creating the `pattern` object:

```
Error: '\w'  is an escape sequence not recognized in the string beginning with ""^(\b[A-Z]\w"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the expected result for the sample character vector?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear

Comment: You need to use double escapes in R. Like "\\b" instead of "\b".

Comment: @emsimpson92 Fails on the first word since it's not preceded by a space. Using `\b` would fix that. Also I expect the `"` aren't part of the data but simply R's string delimiter.

Comment: `map_chr(str_extract_all(sentences,'\\b(\\w)(?=\\w{4,})'),paste,collapse="")`?

Comment: @Aaron fixed it. [Here you go](https://regex101.com/r/cvC4V0/7)

Comment: Unless you're using the English language, you shouldn't use `\w`. `\pL` will work for any letter in any language.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, @hmhensen, @emsimpson92. I tried with double escapes `"(?<=^| )\\S(?=\\pL{4,})"`, but the solution do not works. It generate an error: "Error in stri_subset_regex(string, pattern, omit_na = TRUE, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Incorrect Unicode property. (U_REGEX_PROPERTY_SYNTAX)"

Comment: Maybe try using `\\S` instead of `\\pL`. I know there are several flavors of regex and R might have a problem with `\\pL`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to delete all the unwanted characters and remain with the ones you want. From the expected output, it seems you are still using characters from words tht are 3 characters long:

```
 gsub('\\b(\\pL)\\pL{2,}|.','\\U\\1',sentences,perl = TRUE)
[1] "DPCS"   "DSOPGR" "DASP"   "DAI"
```

But if we were to ignore the words you indicated then it would be:

```
gsub('\\b(\\pL)\\pL{4,}|.','\\U\\1',sentences,perl = TRUE)
[1] "DPCS" "DOGR" "DSP"  "DAI"
```

Comment: can you explain why you downvoted? would like to improve

Comment: The answer seems fine to me. Maybe someone just didn't understand it.

Comment: Nice @Onyambu! Thank you so much. It do exactly what I need. Please, let me know if you have some tip to do the same in tidyverse language using pipes.

Comment: Yes, as @emsimpson92 says, an improvement would be a little explanation of the pattern `'\\b(\\pL)\\pL{2,}|.'`

Answer (score 12):

@Onyambu's answer is great, though as a regular expression beginner, it does take me a long time to try to understand it so that I can make modifications to suit my own needs.

Here is my understanding to `gsub('\\b(\\pL)\\pL{4,}|.','\\U\\1',sentences,perl = TRUE)`.
Post in the hope of being helpful to others.

Background information:

- `\\b`: boundary of word
- `\\pL` matches any kind of letter from any language
- `{4,}` is an occurrence indicator

  - {m}: The preceding item is matched exactly m times.
  - {m,}: The preceding item is matched m or more times, i.e., m+
  - {m,n}: The preceding item is matched at least m times, but not more than n times.
- `|` is OR logic operator
- `.` represents any one character except newline.

`\\U\\1` in the replacement text is to reinsert text captured by the pattern as well as capitalize the texts. Note that parentheses `()` create a numbered capturing group in the pattern.

With all the background knowledge, the interpretation of the command is

- replace words matching `\\b(\\pL)\\pL{4,}` with the first letter
- replace any character not matching the above pattern with `""` as nothing is captured for this group

Here are two great places I learned all these backgrounds.

- https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html
- https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern: `(?<=^| )\S(?=\pL{4,})`

I used a positive lookbehind to make sure the matches are preceded by either a space or the beginning of the line. Then I match one character, only if it is followed by 4 or more letters, hence the positive lookahead.

I suggest you don't use `\w` for non-English languages, because it won't match any characters with accents. Instead, `\pL` matches any letter from any language.

Once you have your matches, you can just concatenate them to create your strings (dpcs, dogr, etc...)

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/cvC4V0/9)