# Extract first letter in each word but keeping specific punctuation

Tags: r, regex, replace, gsub

I have a vector with people names with a couple of millions long that I want to remove all characters but the first letter of each word (i.e. initials) and some characters such as ';' and '-'. The vector has large variation in name formats and a small sample would look like this:

```
text <- c("Alwyn Howard Gentry", "a. h. gentry", "A H GENTRY", "A. H. G.", 
          "Carl von Martius", "Leitão Filho, H. F. ; Shepherd, G. J.",
          "Dárdano de Andrade - Lima")
```

I was using the solution below, which gives the desired output, but it is too time-consuming:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(text, " ", fixed = TRUE),
                                   function(x) paste0(substr(x, 1, 1), collapse="")))

"AHG"      "ahg"      "AHG"      "AHG"      "CvM"      "LFHF;SGJ" "DdA-L"
```

So I tried to adapt an answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120034/extract-first-letter-in-each-word-in-r) based on regexp and gsub. I managed to get the initials but not the initals and the characters at the same time:

```
gsub('\\b(\\pL)|.', '\\1', text, perl = TRUE)

"AHG"     "ahg"     "AHG"     "AHG"     "CvM"     "LFHFSGJ" "DdAL"
```

I am really new to regexp. I tried to adapt '\b(\pL)|.' part of the code to include the characters in the pattern but I gave up after a couple of hours trying.

Any ideas on which regular expression I should use to get with gsub() the same result from the one I got with strsplit() and sapply()?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
text <- c("Alwyn Howard Gentry", "a. h. gentry", "A H GENTRY", "A. H. G.", "Carl von Martius", "Leitão Filho, H. F. ; Shepherd, G. J.", "Dárdano de Andrade - Lima")
gsub("(*UCP)(\\b\\p{L}|[;-])(*SKIP)(*F)|.", "", text, perl=TRUE)
## Or, alternatively,
gsub("(*UCP)[^;-](?<!\\b\\p{L})", "", text, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo](https://tio.run/##dY9NTsMwEIX3OcXDKztKfIEWoag0CRAQ6s8CNSC52GoiBTtyXUpFOQziKD1YcFhEsGCk0cwbzfs0Y7vOqTeHcYxnSpJmf9DIzV5YiUxpZw8kAhEcFcdm0AlyZNO7xezhR3HkHBn3fYAhyETYBq9G41ZYV@@2/Wqhanf6MkjrpjJRb0s5RphXqq2UlZGn4NqDfnMuT59WCm0gFRItrfA1RlG/CMKCYLPdrSmh4XJyz2hZrsuyfS8@jqtR/MhoOL@58uMwZcf@OuKzfzZCq2xzvpgtp@wPYPXkbfRifDaA2D@2rvsG) and a [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/KcYe7J/1)/[regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/KcYe7J/2/).

**Details**:

- `(*UCP)` - a PCRE verb that makes `\b` Unicode-aware
- `(\b\p{L}|[;-])(*SKIP)(*F)` - any Unicode letter at the start of a word or a `;` or `-`, and then the match is skipped, and the next match is searched for from the position where the failure occurred
- `|` - or
- `.` - any char but line break chars
- `[^;-](?<!\b\p{L})` - any char but `;` and `-` that are not any Unicode letter that is preceded with either start of string or a non-word char.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for the quick answer, it worked perfectly. After feeling quite dumb with the speed you came up with the solution and demo, I was wondering how do you created the demo at https://regex101.com. You enter the text and the regexp yourself (based on your regex previous knowledge) or does this platform helps you creating the regexp by highlighting or cliking in the desidered pattern?

Comment: @R.Lima The regex needs to be written manually, but there are lots of cheatsheets and help all around. The patterns you need are not basic.