# Keep only the first letter of each word after a comma

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

I have strings like `Sacher, Franz Xaver` or `Nishikawa, Kiyoko`.

Using R, I want to change them to `Sacher, F. X.` or `Nishikawa, K.`.

In other words, the first letter of each word after the comma should be retained with a dot (and a whitespace if another word follows).

[Here is a related response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120034/extract-first-letter-in-each-word-in-r), but it cannot be applied to my case 1:1 as it does not have a comma in its strings; it seems that the simple addition of `(<?=, )` does not work.

E.g. in the following attempts, `gsub()` replaces everything, while my `str_replace_all()`-attempt leads to an error:

```
TEST <- c("Sacher, Franz Xaver", "Nishikawa, Kiyoko", "Al-Assam, Muhammad")

# first attempt
# (resembles the response from the other thread)
gsub('\\b(\\pL)\\pL{2,}|.','\\U\\1', TEST, perl = TRUE)

# second attempt
# error: "Incorrect unicode property"
stringr::str_replace_all(TEST, '(?<=, )\\b(\\pL)\\pL{2,}|.','\\U\\1')
```

I would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub("(*UCP)^[^,]+(*SKIP)(*F)|\\b(\\p{L})\\p{L}*", "\\U\\1.", TEST, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VBs7II/2). *Details*:

- `(*UCP)` - the PCRE verb that will make `\b` Unicode aware
- `^[^,]+(*SKIP)(*F)` - start of string and then any zero or more chars other than a comma, and then the match is failed and skipped, the next match starts at the location where the failure occurred
- `|` - or
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\p{L})` - Group 1: any Unicode letter
- `\p{L}*` - zero or more Unicode letters

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/OCf6pW):

```r
TEST <- c("Sacher, Franz Xaver", "Nishikawa, Kiyoko", "Al-Assam, Muhammad")
gsub("(*UCP)^[^,]+(*SKIP)(*F)|\\b(\\p{L})\\p{L}*", "\\U\\1.", TEST, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "Sacher, F. X." "Nishikawa, K." "Al-Assam, M."
```

Comment: FYI: see the importance of `(*UCP)` verb in [this R demo](https://ideone.com/1sKReK).

Answer (score 2):

A crude approach splitting the string :

```
TEST <- c("Sacher, Franz Xaver", "Nishikawa, Kiyoko", "Al-Assam, Muhammad")

sapply(strsplit(TEST, '\\s+'), function(x) 
      paste0(x[1], paste0(substr(x[-1], 1, 1), collapse = '.'), '.'))

#[1] "Sacher,F.X."  "Nishikawa,K." "Al-Assam,M."
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using multiple backreference:

```
gsub("(\\b\\w+,\\s)(\\b\\w).*(\\b\\w)*", "\\1\\2.\\3", TEST)
[1] "Sacher, F."    "Nishikawa, K." "Al-Assam, M."
```

Here, we use three capturing groups to refer back to in `gsub`'s replacment argument via backreference:

- `(\\b\\w+,\\s)`: this, first, group captures the last name plus the comma followed by whitespace
- `(\\b\\w)`: this, second, group captures the initial of the first name
- `(\\b\\w)`: this, third, group captures the initial of the middle name